# Getting a nil:NilClass error with an array, not sure why

Tags: ruby

I am getting an error that '+' is undefined for nil:NilClass. I'm assuming this comes at

```
index[word] += 1
```

but am not sure why. I'm using 1.9.3.

If ayone could help, it would be appreciated!
Thanks

```
def most_common_words(text)
text_split = text.split(' ')
index = {}
text_split.each do |word| 
    puts index
    puts word
    if (index[word]
        index[word] += 1 )
    else(
        index[word] = 1 )
    end
end
index.to_a.sort[0..2]
```

Comment: Those are some crazy parentheses. That's a hint.

Comment: `index[word] == nil`, which is default value for `Hash`, unless specified other value - that's why you get this error (you try to call `+` method on `nil`). What do you want to with this code?

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks! (Still getting used to Ruby syntax--it's so simple I trip myself up!)

Comment: It's not so simple you got it right, though-the comment isn't the reason your choice is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is *barely* correct.

It ignores the actual problem, which is that your malformed `if` statement.

The code works as written if you fix your syntax:

```
index = {}
%w[ohai kthx ohai].each do |word|
  if index[word]
    index[word] += 1
  else
    index[word] = 1
  end
end
puts index.inspect
=> {"ohai"=>2, "kthx"=>1}
```

Or you could just provide a default value:

```
index2 = Hash.new(0)
%w[ohai kthx ohai].each do |word|
  index2[word] += 1
end
puts index2.inspect
=> {"ohai"=>2, "kthx"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify this code into fewer lines. It will make it look nicer and cleaner.

```
    def most_common_words(text)
      text_split = text.split(' ')
      index = Hash.new(1)
      text_split.each do |key, value|
        puts "The key is #{key} and the value is #{value}"
        index[key] += 1
      end
    end
    index.to_a.sort[0..2]
```

Comment: @DaveNewton Was it the missing "? I just noticed that